# Should a function allowed to throw OperationCanceledException if the passed token was CancellationToken.None?

Tags: .net, cancellation, cancellation-token

Note: a lot of C# methods now take an *optional* cancelation token parameter, with a default value of `default` that typically means same as `CancellationToken.None` when not supplied. But in case there is no default method parameter value, or the default is interpreted to mean something different, please also consider that someone could try to pass `CancellationToken.None` explicity.

Is there a design guideline around whether those methods should be allowed to throw an `OperationCanceledException` even though nobody actually passed them a token which will be set to canceled state? What should this guideline be?

[Consequently, is the caller going to have to think about whether to write the `catch (OperationCanceledException) {}` regardless of whether they pass a token or not? If so, what is the point of having the default behavior mean no cancelation, even though it sounds like a negative factor for usability?]

Answer (score 2):

As a developer experienced with async methods, I would find it very unexpected for a method to throw an OperationCanceledException after passing in CancellationToken.None or default.

If, for some reason, you want to enforce that a "real" CancellationToken is passed, you should check the CanBeCanceled property of the passed token at the beginning of the method (it will be false for CancellationToken.None). If the property is false, you should throw an ArgumentException to inform the caller of the problem. I would still find this unexpected but it would be much less confusing.

Comment: Thanks for teaching us all to use `.CanBeCanceled`

Answer (score 2):

> what is the point of having the default behavior mean no cancelation...?

The default *argument* is a cancellation token that will never be cancelled, because there are a lot of contexts where you don't have a cancellation token available, and there's no point making people write more code when a sane default value is available.

That doesn't *always* mean the default *behavior* means no cancellation. For example, it's possible your `HttpClient` has a [Timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=net-6.0) set, but your [`GetAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync?view=net-6.0) call doesn't provide a `CancellationToken`. `GetAsync` can still throw an `OperationCanceledException` (specifically a `TaskCanceledException`) when the request times out.

> Is there a design guideline around whether those methods should be allowed to throw an `OperationCanceledException` even though nobody actually passed them a token which will be set to canceled state?

No. There are plenty of cases where a given method might throw one of any number of exceptions, just because one of the methods *it calls* threw that exception and it didn't know what to do with it. It would be problematic to say a method isn't *allowed* to throw a particular kind of exception unless you provide a particular type of argument.

As in the HttpClient example, there are cases where an operation could be cancelled even though your call to the method didn't provide the cancellation token that canceled it. Perhaps an application responds to certain state changes (like a particular window being closed, or a server app pool being asked to shut down), by cancelling any active async operations.

In fact, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.operationcanceledexception?view=net-6.0#remarks) for OperationCancelledException explicitly accounts for the possibility that an operation is cancelled by something other than a cancellation token:

> **If** the task that was canceled had an associated cancellation token, it is returned by the CancellationToken property, and the CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested property of the token is set to true.

There would be no need for that "**If**", if cancellation always had to come from a token.

> Consequently, is the caller going to have to think about whether to write the `catch (OperationCanceledException) {}` regardless of whether they pass a token or not?

This decision has very little to do with whether a method is given a `CancellationToken`, and much more to do with whether the calling code would know what to do with an `OperationCanceledException`. The usual rules for catching (or not catching) exceptions apply just as much here: it's often best just to let exceptions work their way up the call stack, until they reach a point where you can do something useful with the error.

Comment: Thanks, interesting POV. I always previously considered this behavior of HttpClient.GetAsync throwing OperationCanceledException as very surprising, or potentially an example of 'why not to do it that way'. The idea that there might be more than one way for an action to get cancelled, is sort of convincing.. however, if its canceled for some reason external to the caller, won't they want to know about how and why it is canceled in more detail? A lot of things might seem superficially similar to canceling like IOException, TimeoutException, ThreadAbortException. Imagine instead getting an OCE.

Comment: Yep, these are hard architectural decisions. Note, for example, how the timeout behavior of GetAsync has shifted, from throwing an HttpRequestException in .NET Framework, to an OperationCanceledException with no inner exception in .NET Core, to an OperationCanceledException with a TimeoutException as its inner exception in .NET 5+. I like the latter because it correctly captures the fact that the operation was cancelled, while also providing more detail about why it was canceled. But there's no obvious "right" answer in cases like these.